# How to pass filter to a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I have a custom directive and I want to be able to pass a filter name to it. That filter will then be use in my template. Here is what I got so far:

the directive:

```
angular.module('forecastDirective', [])
.directive('forecast', ['appConfig', function(appConfig) {
    return {
        templateUrl: appConfig.directivesRoot + 'templates/forecast.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            weatherObject: "=",
            convertToDate: "&",
            filterTemp: "@",
            dateFormat: "@",
        },
    }
}]);
```

The template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ convertToDate({ dt: weatherObject.dt }) | date: dateFormat }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Daytime temperature: {{ weatherObject.temp.day | filterTemp }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As @AmyBlankenship's answer states, you don't need to inject or pass it to the directive definition.  It should be available to the template as is.  If it is not, then you might need to check to see if that filter is available to the module your directive is defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way is, using the `$filter` service and a function in the scope that delegates to the correct filter:

```
angular.module('forecastDirective', [])
.directive('forecast', ['appConfig', function(appConfig) {
    return {
        templateUrl: appConfig.directivesRoot + 'templates/forecast.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            weatherObject: "=",
            convertToDate: "&",
            filterTemp: "@",
            dateFormat: "@",
        },
        controller: ['$filter', '$scope', function($filter, $scope) {
            $scope.filterFn = function(in) {
                return $filter($scope.filterTemp)(in);
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

A downside is that you can no longer use it as a filter:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        Daytime temperature: {{ filterFn(weatherObject.temp.day) }}
    </div>
```

I guess the intended filter function returns a primitive (string, number, boolean). If it returns something complex (object, array), you may need to cache return values to avoid infinite digest cycles.

---

You can implement a meta-filter:

```
angular.module(...)
    .filter('metafilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        return function(input, filterName) {
            return $filter(filterName)(input);
        };
    }]);
```

Use it as:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        Daytime temperature: {{ weatherObject.temp.day | metafilter:filterTemp }}
    </div>
```

This is a fiddle demonstrating the metafilter: https://jsfiddle.net/opL1zfzd/

Comment: I know I can use a function, but is there anyway that I can just pass the filter I want, or is it impossible?

Comment: You *can* do it by manipulating the template in a `compile` function. You don't want to do that. You can also compile yourself the HTML fragment that includes the filter name. You do not want that either (too complex for no reason). I do not know any other way to *structurally* change the template dynamically. On the other hand, you can implement a meta-filter that does what the `filterFn` above does, but in the packaging of a filter. I will update the question, if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have access to it in the controller to use it in the View. That's kind of the point of filters. If you actually needed it in the controller, you could request it by itself by asking for `filterTempFilter` to be injected. Or you can have the $filter provider injected and ask for your specific filter from it.